# Why is 'audience' set to 'localhost:<port>' with auth0?

Tags: authentication, auth0

I'm using auth0 with a React Native app and am using some copied code which is working. I'm trying to understand what `audience` means and how it is used. The docs say the audience identifies the resource owner, and in my code it's set to 'http://localhost:". This is a loopback, so I'm assuming that when auth0 actually uses `audience`, it calls it relative to the resource server.
Can anyone explain what's happening here? How does auth0 identify the machine relative to which it calls `audience`, and is the audience always the same as this machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `audience` parameter to make a determination which resource server the user is authorizing access to. By default, Auth0 issues an opaque token which has limited use on some of our API endpoints. For example, an opaque access_token is issued when specifying the `/userinfo` endpoint as the `audience`.

Actually audience is an identifier for a resource server (API) so once you create an API in Auth0 with a set audience, it is used then to identity the API and cannot be changed. It's recommended to use a URI but it's not actually necessary since this is just a unique identifier.

You applications then try to authorize to the API and getting tokens by passing the audience of the API in the /authorize and /oauth/token endpoints depending on the OAuth2 grants you are using.